# Where are the images?

Tags: patent-figures

In reference to the patent: [WO2017013302A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2017013302A1)

Answer (score 0):

The query refers to WIPO publication number. To view figures one can browse WIPO patent search. Link https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/search.jsf. Select field combination under search.

For this application, use **title** (System and method for guided implantoplasty) or **publication no**. (WO2017013302A1) or **PCT application no**. (PCT/ES2016/070559) for **search**.

Click on search. Click on Drawing on next page to see figures. One can also see drawings after clicking on documents and then clicking on Application as filed.

Directly these links can be browsed for this application.
 (https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/detail.jsf?docId=WO2017013302&recNum=1&tab=Drawings&maxRec=&office=&prevFilter=&sortOption=&queryString=) else (https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/detail.jsf?docId=WO2017013302&recNum=1&tab=PCTDocuments&maxRec=&office=&prevFilter=&sortOption=&queryString=).